# Use pthread_create to invoke a C function of the type "int argc, char** argv -> int"

Tags: c, pthreads

I need to use pthread_create to invoke a C function of type

```
int main_original(int argc, char** argv)
```

I have tried something like this:

```
pthread_create(&t, NULL, main_original, NULL);
```

The compiler gives me a type error

> invalid conversion from ‘int (*)(int, char**)’ to ‘void* (*)(void*)’

So, what is the right way to invoke main_original so that its parameters are well passed?

Comment: Have you considered calling it through a wrapper function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: invalid conversion from ‘int (\*)(void\*)’ to ‘void\* (\*)(void\*)’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36039970/error-invalid-conversion-from-int-void-to-void-void)

Comment: If you had [searched for that error message here at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=invalid+conversion+from+%E2%80%98int+%28*%29%28int%2C+char**%29%E2%80%99+to+%E2%80%98void*+%28%29%28void%29%E2%80%99), you would have found multiple relevant answers to your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function `pthread_create` is only able to call functions with the following signature:

```
void *fn(void *)
```

Even if you did manage to cast a pointer to a function with a different signature and successfully pass it to `pthread_create`, your program is likely to crash as `pthread_create` will attempt to set up the stack / registers in a way that follows the platform's calling convention for a function with just one `void *` argument, which will lead to your function being in an indeterminate state.

The way to solve your problem would be to use a wrapper function specifically designed for being called by `pthread_create` like so:

```
void *main_original_start_routine(void *arg)
{
    main_original(argc, argv);
    return NULL;
}
```

However, this may not be enough, unless `argc` and `argv` are global variables.  You may find you also need to somehow pass these values through to this function from the scope in which you call `pthread_create`.  This can be done via the `void *arg` argument to `pthread_create`, by creating a struct holding the state you need, and passing it around via a casted void pointer:

```
struct main_original_context {
    int argc;
    char **argv;
};

void *main_original_start_routine(void *arg)
{
    /* Convert the void pointer back to the struct pointer it
     * really is. */
    struct main_original_context *ctx = arg;
    main_original(ctx->argc, ctx->argv);
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pthread_t t;

    struct main_original_context ctx = {
        argc,
        argv
    };

    /* Pass a pointer to our context struct to the thread routine. */
    pthread_create(&t, NULL, &main_original_start_routine, &ctx);

    pthread_join(&t, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Keep in mind however, that `ctx` only has a lifetime of the duration of the `main` function in this case.  If the function we create the pthread in does not join with `pthread_join` before returning (and invalidating the struct used to provide context to the thread), then this would be unsafe.  Therefore we would have to use dynamic allocation, and make the thread assume responsibility for freeing any dynamically allocated memory:

```
struct main_original_context {
    int foo;
    int bar;
};

void *foobar_start_routine(void *arg)
{
    struct main_original_context *ctx = arg;
    foobar(ctx->foo, ctx->bar);

    /* Free memory we have been given responsibility for. */
    free(ctx);

    return NULL;
}

void asdf(int foo, int bar)
{
    pthread_t t;

    struct main_original_context *ctx;

    /* Allocate memory. */
    ctx = malloc(sizeof *ctx);

    ctx->foo = foo;
    ctx->bar = bar;

    /* Assume `main_original_start_routine` is now responsible for freeing
     * `ctx`. */
    pthread_create(&t, NULL, &foobar_start_routine, ctx);

    /* Now we can safely leave this scope without `ctx` being lost.  In
     * the real world, `t` should still be joined somewhere, or
     * explicitly created as a "detached" thread. */
}
```